# How to get a webpage to re-access the database when reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring, hibernate

There are profiles, and each profile can have an assigned "master". Each master can have several different profiles (which is the whole point of the master), and each profile can either have no master or just one.
I have two fields: a dropdown menu (populated by the database) and a text field. There is a Save button next to the text field. If the initial dropdown menu selection is any of the "masters" in the menu, the text field auto-populates with the selection, for the user to edit. If they change the text field, i.e. from "Master, Inc." to "Master, Incorporated", and click the button, it will change the name of the master in the database, and reload the page. The new master name will be "Master, Incorporated". This is what I want. However, if the dropdown selection is changed to something other than the initial selection, and then that one is edited and the button is clicked, the page will reload and show the original selection before it was changed. However, the assigned master has in fact changed in the database, evidenced by both manually checking in Oracle and also leaving the page and then reaccessing it manually, in which case it will finally update.
Similarly, if they select "Create New Master" in the dropdown, the text field is blank, and it behaves a little differently. They can enter a new master name, and clicking the button will create a new entry in the database, and assign it to the profile selected. This has the same problem: the database updates, but the form doesn't change unless you manually leave and then search for the profile again.
If the dropdown selection is null, the button and text field are both disabled, which is fine.

I've tried location.reload() and location.reload(true), but neither have any effect. If I kick the user from the profile after they click the button, when they reaccess the profile it updates, but obviously this isn't what I'm looking for.

```
    function editMaster(){
        var agentID = document.getElementById("agentID").value;
        var updated = new Date();
        updated = updated.toShortFormat();
        var newName = document.getElementById("agentName").value;
        var updateID = document.getElementById("agentDropdown").value

        var jsonURL = "${urlBase}"+"/editMaster/" + newName + "/" + updated + "/" + updateID + "/" + agentID + ".json?jsoncallback=?";
        var xhttp = jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function(obj, textStatus){
            window.location.reload(true);
        });
    }

    function addMaster(obj){
        var agentID = document.getElementById("agentID").value;
        var created = new Date();
        created = created.toShortFormat();
        var updated = created;
        var updateID = document.getElementById("agentDropdown").value;
        var createID = (parseInt(updateID, 10) + 1);
        var newName = document.getElementById("agentName").value;
        var create = "  Create New Agent Master";
        if(newName == null || newName == ""){
            alert("You have to enter a new name to add it.");
        }
        else{
            var jsonURL = '${urlBase}/addMaster/' + newName + '/' + updated + '/' + updateID + '/' + created + '/' + createID + '/' + create + '/' + agentID + '.json?jsoncallback=?';
            var xhttp = jQuery.getJSON(jsonURL, function(obj, textStatus){
                window.location.reload(true);
            });

        }
    }
```

These both work as expected, other than window.location.reload(true); not updating the page properly. As mentioned, the database does indeed update, but the form itself doesn't update unless the page is left entirely and then reaccessed. While the user could simply be kicked back to the search page, and reaccess the page, that isn't acceptable, and I need to eliminate that extra step for the user. If it matters, the database updates are done in a different file than the jsp. The RequestMapping is done in a controller, which separates all the variables and passes them to a function in ProfileDao.java.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Dropdown you are populating with database is not being rendered in page load. You are populating the dropdown in the search page or any earlier stage. Try populating the dropdown in the page where you want to reflect the changes.

Comment: It's created and populated in the JSP file that contains all of the information on the form.

Comment: you can add a script like these in your jsp file.
link --> https://codeshare.io/21BLRq

what this code does is on clicking save button  drop down is re populated.